# How to create image captions with 'alt' text using jquery click function

Tags: jquery, click, caption, alt

I'm creating an image gallery that shows the alt text as captions for each individual image. Right now I have something that uses the mouseenter/mouseleave function for this desired result.

JS

```
$(function () {
    $(".thumb").mouseenter(function () {
        var $t = $(this);
        var $d = $("<div>");
        $d.addClass("desc").text($t.attr("alt")).css({
            width: $t.width(),
            height: $t.height() - 20,
            top: $t.position().top
        });
        $t.after($d).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
        $d.mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("fast", 0, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            }).siblings("img.thumb").fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img class="thumb" src="myImage1" alt="caption">
</div>
<div>
    <img class="thumb" src="myImage2" alt="caption">
</div>
```

Here's an example of what I had in mind in terms of how the captions will look visually.
http://jsfiddle.net/CTQvN/168/

Basically I want to be able to show the captions of multiple images simultaneously by clicking on a link somewhere on the page that looks like a button, instead of the mouseenter functions so that I can accommodate to smartphones an other devices without a mouse. I'd like to maintain the visual aesthetics of this current script while updating the function portion of what I have so far. I'm very new to JavaScript and I realize that my code is not the best right now so please bear with me on this one. I'm very open to suggestions, and I'm extremely willing to learn how to get this to work. Cheers!

Comment: You could change "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" to "click"

Comment: Alright. That seems easy enough. How do I write the added script to associate the link that shows and hides the caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CTQvN/170/)

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
    $(this).trigger('mouseenter'); 
});
```

Or if you'd like a button:

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CTQvN/169/)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.thumb').trigger('mouseenter'); 
});
```

Comment: Dear Lord, thank you Alex Morrise. That's exactly what I've been looking for. Is there a way to make the captions disappear upon a second click of the link?